# How to specify xUnit Test Names in .runsettings file

Tags: xunit, vstest, runsettings

I have a XUnit test project. I am planning to use .runsettings file and I need to specify the TEST NAMES which I have to run in .runsettings file.

I am going to run the test in commandline using "dotnet vstest" command and specifying the test dll and settings file. I am using runsettings for the first time.

My issue is I dont have idea about how to specify test names to be run in runsettings file. Can anybody please help me on this?